# Stored Procedure Stopped working and recompile fixed it

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a stored procedure that works perfectly fine. It is being accessed by many web forms and it takes 20 parameters; but suddenly, it stops working for no reason and recompile fix it again. What can be the reason? BTW it is a quite complex stored procedure which accesses 10 tables to extract data and apply sorting as well.

If I run the stored procedure using SQL Server, it returns data properly without any issue, but when I use my .net application to execute that same procedure, it keeps loading and loading and returns nothing at the end .. so it may be a connection issue.

Comment: What do you mean by not working?  Error out or just takes forever to run?

Comment: You need to explain the actual issue. What do you mean it stopped working? Surely it didn't suddenly start producing random results or melting your hard drive. What does "not working" mean in this context. My guess is you changed the parameters and the cached plan was inapproriate for the new values. This could be caused by a LOT of things. The answer starts by sharing your code, not a vague description.

Comment: i updated my question .. please sugges now

Comment: Sounds like a classic case of [parameter sniffing](https://sqlinthewild.co.za/index.php/2007/11/27/parameter-sniffing/) to me.

Comment: Parameter Sniffing made my SP very very slow.. so i used "WITH RECOMPILE" so far its working fine

Answer (score 0):

you easiest fix is to take the params from front end. And then re-assign them internally to another set of variables. Because having that many params is botching up your execution plan and leading to param sniffing. eg of script would be:

```
alter proc xyz
(
    @startdate date
    , @Stopdate date
) as 
    declare @internal_Startdate as date
        , @internal_Enddate as date

    set @internal_Startdate = @StartDate; 
    set @internal_Enddate = @EndDate; 

    --..select logic here..
```

Comment: This would be a better answer if you explained why this works and format the code so it is legible.

Comment: Reason is: Because having that many params is botching up your execution plan and leading to param sniffing.

Comment: Put that in your answer and explain what it means. I took care of the formatting for you.

Comment: Parameter Sniffing made my SP very very slow.. so i used "WITH RECOMPILE" so far its working fine

Comment: with recompile scraps your execution plan everytime. Defeats the purpose of having a SP. Have to keep broader pix in mind that stats are being updated, have all right indexes etc. But again if this works for ya then great.